# How to cut image in four quadrant(equal parts) using Opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with Open CV for image processing but I am facing problem in cutting the image in four equal parts or four quadrant.

I have to do this process in C++ code so please can any one help me?

Answer (score 6):

It's better to use [**`Mat::(Range rowRange, Range colRange)`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6) here:

```
cv::Mat top_left 
   = img(cv::Range(0, img.rows / 2 - 1), cv::Range(0, img.cols / 2 - 1));
cv::Mat top_right 
   = img(cv::Range(0, img.rows / 2 - 1), cv::Range(img.cols / 2, img.cols - 1));
cv::Mat bottom_left 
   = img(cv::Range(img.rows / 2, img.rows - 1), cv::Range(0, img.cols / 2 - 1));
cv::Mat bottom_right 
   = img(cv::Range(img.rows / 2, img.rows - 1), cv::Range(img.cols / 2, img.cols - 1));
```

And, to show them in different windows:

```
cv::imshow("top_left", top_left);
cv::imshow("top_right", top_right);
cv::imshow("bottom_left", bottom_left);
cv::imshow("bottom_right", bottom_right);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining four `cv::Rect`s:

```
cv::Rect top_left(cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Size(img.size().height/2, img.size().width/2));
cv::Rect top_right(cv::Point(0, img.size().width/2 + 1), cv::Size(img.size().height/2, img.size().width/2));
// bottom_right, bottom_left by analogy
...
cv::Mat top_right_quadrant;
cv::Mat top_left_quadrant;
top_right_quadrant = img(top_right);
top_left_quadrant = img(top_left);
// bottom_right, bottom_left by analogy
```

You surely still need to account for off-by-one errors and you need to decide how to split the image, if it has an odd number of row/columns